# generate 4 digit unique identity key based on date

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, numbers, unique-key

I need to generate unique key to store in sql .
suppose we have date "2013/07/25" for today
how we can generate unique 4 digit key based on everyday date ?

Comment: A four digit key could be used to indicate every day in ca 27 year range period. Is this enough for your date ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a 4 digit key you could represent every day from a predefined base and start counting from that base.

For example (using 1/1/2000 as base) :

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2000,1,1);
DateTime dtEnd = dt.AddDays(9999);
Console.WriteLine("Maximum date available:" + dtEnd.ToShortDateString());

dtEnd = new DateTime(2013,7,25);
TimeSpan ts = dtEnd - dt;
Console.WriteLine("Today Day number from base: " + ts.TotalDays);
```

Of course you could easily fine-tune your range changing the base date and setting it to a different value. However, once set and starting to save data in db it will be not easy to change the base value. I would recommend to avoid this pattern and choose a more flexible way to store unique keys in a table, but, of course, I don't know your requirements.

Comment: what if there are more than 1 record for each day?

Comment: No way then to have a unique key without bringing in some other fields like a progressive count or a minutes counter. But, I have to ask, a simple date  saved as date is out of question?

Comment: i didnt get what u mean?

Comment: If you have more than one record for one day then a key based on day count from a starting point is not enough because you can't differentiate the number 4954 (today count from 1/1/2000). So you need another field in the database that together to the first field becomes your unique key (say a DayNumber and a MinuteCounter field) where in DayNumber you store the day number from the starting base and in MinuteCounter you store the minute in which you insert the new record (or second depending on the frequency) You tell the database engine to use two fields as unique key for the record

Answer (score 1):

I would take the days since some date, such as '2010-01-01'.  This will give you up to 10,000 days, which is a bit under 30 years.

Here is a method for doing so:

```
select right('0000'+cast(datediff(day, '2010-01-01', @YOURDATE) as varchar(4)), 4)
```